# not enough arguments for format string help please Python

Tags: python

```
a = '%s eggs'
b = '%s cheese'
c = '%s bread'
d = '%s tomato'
e ='%s cucumber'
shopping_list = a+b+c+d+e
print(shopping_list)
for x in range(0,5):
    print(shopping_list %x)
```

output
Type Error: not enough arguments for format string
I am learning and this is my homework :)

Comment: Where do you set `a`?

Comment: @Alex028502 it was hidden by wrong formatting !

Comment: What are u trying to achieve?

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name. It is a bad practice to overwrite any built-in symbol (`print`, `list`, `int`, `open` ....) or else `print` won't print etc.

Comment: good point - I edited that part since it is unrelated to the current error

Answer (score 0):

After you print `list`, you will see a string with a number of `%s` in it (five of them)

when  you format that string with the `%` operating on the last line, it is expecting `x` to be a tuple with as many values as you have `%s` in your string, but you are just giving a single value

So it is complaining that you have given it a string with five `%s` and trying to format it with something other than a list of five values to put in their place.

https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/#1-old-style-string-formatting-operator

---

try replacing `shopping_list` with `a` on the last line and see what happens; it'll be happy with a single value because `a` only has one `%s` in it

---

you can covert the whole range into something that can format your big string like this

```
shopping_list % tuple(range(0,5))
```

or you might be looking for a list of strings instead of one big string

```
shopping_list = [a, b, c, d, e]
```

try this to see the difference:

```
print([a, b, c, d, e]) # list of little strings
print(a + b + c + d + e) # one big string
```

then in your final print line, instead of using `shopping_list`, you will have to use the current element of `shopping_list`

try replacing the final line with this for example if you have turned `shopping_list` into a list

```
print(shopping_list[0] % x)
```